# Regex: Not between 1 and 5 characters in length

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/.{1,5}/
```

allows for any character up to 4 times.

What is the Regex to allow for 0 characters OR 5+ characters? Essentially the inverse of **/.{1,5}/**

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just check the length of the string?

Comment: By any character, do you mean any possible character up to 4 times (AKA length of 4) or do you mean one specific character is only allowed 4 times?

Comment: If you really need to do this with regex, you can easily craft one that will match either 0 characters or more than 5 (tip : match more than five with the `{n,}` quantifier, and make that optional)

Comment: _“allows for any character up to 4 times”_ ... rather up to 5; and of course absolutely any arbitrary characters before or after that. Unless you anchor your pattern to the start and end, this only checks if 1 to 5 characters are _contained_ in your input string.

Comment: `/(?:.{5,})?/` - "optionally match five or more"

Comment: /^$|.{5,}/ - match an empty string or any character at least times

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol `/(?:.{5,})?/.test("123") === true`, you need to add ^$ or it will take the empty match for anything.

Comment: @Amy: Of course I'm open to any alternatives as Regex is not my strong suite, but it appears as if both /^$|.{5,}/ and /^(.{6,}$)|^()$/ work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex should be:

```
    var rx = /^(.{6,}$)|^()$/;
    console.log(rx.test("")); // true
    console.log(rx.test("12345")); // false
    console.log(rx.test("123456")); // true
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks.